Get deep data using JMS\SerializedName
I have json
"CheckSum":{
    "NumberRecordings":"1",
    "Total":"1"
}

And have model
final class RegisterModel
{
    #[
        Assert\NotBlank,
        JMS\SerializedName('CheckSum.NumberRecordings')
    ]
    private string $contractNumber;
}

Next, I'm trying to deserialize the data
final readonly class XmlParseAction implements FileParseStrategyInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private JMS\Serializer\SerializerInterface $serializer
    )

    public function __invoke(string $jsonDocument)
    {
         $model = $this->serializer->deserialize($arrayXML, RegisterModel::class, 'json')
    }
}

But the value of the field is null, at the same time, if you try to get a field of the first level, then everything works correctly.
Is there any solution to assign a value from nested structures to this field?

What's nested? Your JSON only has one object.

Where does $arrayXML come from?
